# Safari calculates wrong width in table

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, html-table

I'm working on developing a simple column resize functionality for HTML tables.

The table works OK so far - **except in Safari** (ver 5.1.4). For some reason Safari gives the cell widths a negative(!) value.

a JSFiddle is available here: [simple-resize](http://jsfiddle.net/sangil/kcAUM/)

The negative column width values can be seen if the `style="width"` attributes are removed from the `<th>` elements (or disabled in the code inspector)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tblcont" id="cont">
<table id="table1" class="pivot-table pivot-fixed-layout">
    <thead>
        <tr id="tr1">
            <th style="width: 52px;">city</th>
            <th style="width: 26px;"># c</th>
            <th style="width: 37px;"># id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tel Aviv</td>
            <td>814</td>
            <td>1,047</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Natanya</td>
            <td>805</td>
            <td>1,016</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.pivot-table.pivot-fixed-layout {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 0;
}

.pivot-table td, .pivot-table th {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 6px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.pivot-table th {
    cursor: col-resize;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var pressed = false,
    $column,
    $table = $("table"),
    startX, startWidth,
    tableInitialWidth = $('#cont').width() - 100,
    currentTableWidth, newTableWidth;

$("table th").mousedown(function(e) {
    $column = $(this);
    pressed = true;
    startX = e.pageX;
    startWidth = $column.width();
    $column.addClass("resizing");
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if(pressed) {

        var delta = e.pageX - startX,
            currentColumnWidth,
            newColumnWidth;

        currentColumnWidth = $column.width();
        newColumnWidth = startWidth + delta;

        currentTableWidth = $table.width();
        newTableWidth = currentTableWidth + delta;

        // no not make columns smaller than min width
        if (newColumnWidth > 2) {
            $column.width(newColumnWidth);
        }
    }
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
    if(pressed) {
        $column.removeClass("resizing");
        pressed = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: the question is why Safari gives a negative width to the table cells